# 2008 Clustered Services (SQL) to 2008 R2 Clustered Services

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, cluster

I've found plenty of articles for upgrading SQL in a clustered environment from SQL 2008 to SQL 2008 R2. However, I have not found much information in relation to migrating a current Server 2008 Failover Cluster running multiple SQL versions to a Server 2008 R2 Failover Cluster.

Since you can't join a 2008 R2 server to a 2008 failover cluster, what is the process for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle is to do a clean install of Windows 2008 R2 on one of the servers and reinstall all of your apps (i.e., SQL Server). Then use the Failover Cluster Migration Wizard to move your services from the old cluster to the new one. The install Windows 2008 R2 and apps on the other server.

When you install SQL Server, make sure you patch it with exactly the same patches as the old one.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182314%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Is this basically the steps? 1. Setup new cluster with 2008 R2 server(s). 2. Run SQL setup (cluster node setup?). 3. Run migration wizard in the failover manager to migrate SQL clustered instances.

Comment: Yes. The link I posted gives the details.

Answer (score 0):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134(v=sql.105).aspx for the list of steps to accomplish the task.

Comment: That has the steps to create a SQL cluster, but not the actual migration. Nothing really specifies if I need to install the new SQL instances standalone or as a new cluster either. What's annoying is I don't want new SQL instances, but since I need to install SQL before doing the migration, I need to install them in any case.